# Customizing retry delays with Amazon SQS from Shoryuken (ruby)

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, sidekiq, shoryuken

I am migrating a background job processing service made with [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) to [shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken), which is based on [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).
With **sidekiq** you can customize the retries pattern by using `sidekiq_retry_in`:

```
class WorkerWithCustomRetry
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options :retry => 5

    sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
        retry_count(count)
    end

    def self.retry_count(count)
    ...
    end
end
```

where, in my case, `retry_count`returns the delay for the next retry based on external configuration.
With **shoryuken** retries are yielded to SQS which handle retries automatically as long as the message is not deleted by the consumer application. However with **shoryuken** you can change the delay by using `retry_intervals` but [documentation](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/wiki/Worker-options#retry_intervals) only explains how to set fixed values:

```
class MyWorker
    include Shoryuken::Worker

    shoryuken_options queue: 'default', retry_intervals: [360, 1200, 3600] # 5.minutes, 20.minutes and 1.hour

end
```

I need to customize the delay for retries the same way as with **sidekiq**, using a `retry_count` method which returns different values depending on external data. Is this possible or does exist a workaround to do that with **shoryuken**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Shoryuken only supports fixed values for exponential backoff, but you can submit a PR changing [ExponentialBackoffRetry](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/blob/master/lib/shoryuken/middleware/server/exponential_backoff_retry.rb) with:

```
# https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/blob/290b1cb4c4c40f34881d7f7b7a3beda949099cf5/lib/shoryuken/middleware/server/exponential_backoff_retry.rb#L11

retry_intervals = worker.class.get_shoryuken_options['retry_intervals']

retry_intervals = if retry_intervals.respond_to? :call
                    retry_intervals.call(worker, queue, sqs_msg, body)
                  else
                    Array(retry_intervals)
                  end
```

So you will be able to use a proc or fixed values to set `retry_intervals`, i.e.:

```
class MyWorker
  include Shoryuken::Worker

  shoryuken_options queue: 'default', 
    retry_intervals: -> (worker, queue, sqs_msg, body) { worker.your_method(...) }
end
```

OR you can remove the default `ExponentialBackoffRetry` and add yours:

```
Shoryuken.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.remove Middleware::Server::ExponentialBackoffRetry
    chain.add YourExponentialBackoffRetry
  end
end
```

But keep in mind that SQS does not officially support exponential backoff, it's something implemented in Shoryuken using the Visibility Timeout, which can extended to a maximum of 12 hours.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html
>
> You can continue to call ChangeMessageVisibility to extend the visibility timeout to a maximum of 12 hours. If you try to extend beyond 12 hours, the request will be rejected.